# page-break-inside: avoid and display: table-row not working properly. Content appears distorted for each first item on each new page

Tags: css, display, page-break-inside

The table has  and  tags as the content that is generated depends on the number of items inside the order.

However, when the PDF is printed, the content of the table overflows and the information about an item is split between 2 sheets, which does not look good.

When applying a page-break-inside: avoid; and display: table-row; to a div, every first generated content inside the table on a new page is spread out. The rest of the generated content appears just fine.

[image: 2nd page of the document]

As you can see, the first part that is generated onto the PDF has its details spread out, unlike the others that follow. This only happens for each first part of each page.

I tried everything I could find on here and on the internet, but made no progress. Can't figure out why only the 1st item of each new page appears spread out, and the rest are ok. Please help!

Comment: Can you please show the code used to generate this pdf ?

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.